# How to convert Seq to RDD when working with spark streaming context

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using `TestSuiteBase` to create some tests with `spark-streaming` (using spark streaming context `scc`). Then I create dummy data using `output: Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]]`. Finally I want to apply some function to `output`, but this function accepts `RDD[(Double, Double)]`, not `Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]]`.

To solve this issue, I am thinking to use `val rdd: RDD[(Double, Double)] = sc.parallelize(output.flatten)`, however how and where exactly should I get spark context `sc` from `scc`? Or, perhaps, there is any way to directly create dummy data in `RDD` without using `Seq`?

```
class StreamingTestLR  extends SparkFunSuite
                       with TestSuiteBase {

  // use longer wait time to ensure job completion
  override def maxWaitTimeMillis: Int = 20000

  var ssc: StreamingContext = _

  override def afterFunction() {
    super.afterFunction()
    if (ssc != null) {
      ssc.stop()
    }
  }

//...

val output: Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]] = runStreams(ssc, numBatches, numBatches)

// THE PROBLEM IS HERE!!!
// val metrics = new SomeFuncThatAcceptsRDD(rdd)

}
```

UPDATE

```
  // Test if the prediction accuracy of increases when using hyper-parameter optimization
  // in order to learn Y = 10*X1 + 10*X2 on streaming data
  test("Test 1") {
    // create model initialized with zero weights
    val model = new StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD()
      .setInitialWeights(Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0))
      .setStepSize(0.2)
      .setNumIterations(25)

    // generate sequence of simulated data for testing
    val numBatches = 10
    val nPoints = 100
    val testInput = (0 until numBatches).map { i =>
      LinearDataGenerator.generateLinearInput(0.0, Array(10.0, 10.0), nPoints, 42 * (i + 1))
    }
    val inputDStream = DStream[LabeledPoint]

    withStreamingContext(setupStreams(testInput, inputDStream)) { ssc =>
      model.trainOn(inputDStream)
      model.predictOnValues(inputDStream.map(x => (x.label, x.features)))
      val output: Seq[Seq[(Double, Double)]] = runStreams(ssc, numBatches, numBatches)


      val rdd: RDD[(Double, Double)] = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(output.flatten)

      // Instantiate metrics object
      val metrics = new RegressionMetrics(rdd)

      // Squared error
      println(s"MSE = ${metrics.meanSquaredError}")
      println(s"RMSE = ${metrics.rootMeanSquaredError}")

      // R-squared
      println(s"R-squared = ${metrics.r2}")

      // Mean absolute error
      println(s"MAE = ${metrics.meanAbsoluteError}")

      // Explained variance
      println(s"Explained variance = ${metrics.explainedVariance}")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 class MyTestSuite extends TestSuiteBase with BeforeAndAfter {

  test("my test") {
    withTestServer(new TestServer()) { testServer =>
      // Start the server
      testServer.start()
      // Set up the streaming context and input streams
      withStreamingContext(new StreamingContext(conf, batchDuration)) { ssc =>
        val rdd = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(output.flatten)
        // your code here 
        testServer.stop()
        ssc.stop()
      }
     }
    }
 }
```

More details here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/InputStreamsSuite.scala

Comment: It says: `Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext`

Comment: could you edit your question with complete code example? did you try to run your test code inside withStreamingContext { ssc => <your code>} ?

Comment: Where TestServer is defined?

Comment: Check the link - it's defined in InputStreamSuite.scala file. But I'm not sure it's required - possibly withStreamingContext will be enough

Comment: Also, for simpler example, you can check test("repartition (fewer partitions)") in [BasicOperationsSuite](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/BasicOperationsSuite.scala#L104)

Comment: I think I am almost done. Please see my Update. The only thing that still is unclear to me is how to use `setupStreams` without reassigning `ssc`.

Comment: I guess you can use `withStreamingContext( setupStreams(testInput, (inputDStream: DStream[LabeledPoint]) => {...}))` - it creates ssc in place, no re-assignment is needed